# How can I solve this limits exercise?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

I have problems with the following exercise:

Let R be the rectangle joining the midpoints of the sides of the quadrilateral $Q$, which has vertices $(±x,0)$ and $(0,±1)$ What is the value of

$$ \lim_{x \to 0^{+}}\frac{\ Perimeter R}{\  PerimeterQ} $$

I want to plot the points on the Cartesian plane in order to draw the figures, and determine their perimeter by adding the distances between points.

However, I don't know which points to choose to express the figures in the Cartesian plane.

Any suggestions, what can I do

Comment: Well find the perimeter and area in terms of $x$, then take the limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint

Here is the case when $x=2$. What are the perimeters of $Q$ and $R$? Can you generalise this for arbitrary $x$?

[image]

Comment: Yessir your answer was very helpful